# Suggestions to save local persistently data on Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm a beginner in Flutter and sometimes I'm not sure about the proper approach to get things done. In this case I would like to save a list of favorites and history views based on an api request. The idea is that when the user reloads the app the data is still on the mobile(let's say they can see their saved bookmarks). I'm not planning to use a database as firebase as I do not need nothing complicated. Which would be the best way/approach to accomplish it? I've been reading sqflite package but not sure if it is the way to go. Please could you give me some thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think shared-preference would perfectly match your need.
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Here you have one article, which describes how to use it: https://medium.com/flutter-community/shared-preferences-how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-554d08671ae9

Answer (score 0):

Yep as @jaop said , Shared Preferences is the best choice , but still if u want most probability of getting the data then u can use , Along with Shared Preferences , Provider or passing data from one page to another . This decreases the chance of not getting data from Shared Preferences , which happens very rarely but still.